# mybatis insert throwing org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, mybatis

I have a insert statement in my xml as below.

```
<insert id="insertQuote" parameterMap="quoteParam">
        <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="string">
            select seq_quote_id.nextval as id from dual
        </selectKey>
        insert into insq_quotation (quote_id, search_product_type,
        coverage_start_date, quote_date, zip, create_date, business_id,
        county,  status
        )
        values(? ,?, ?, sysdate, ?, default, 200, ?,  999)
    </insert>
```

Here is the parameter map

```
<parameterMap id="quoteParam" type="com.product.vo.QuoteVO">
        <parameter property="id" jdbcType="INTEGER"/>
        <parameter property="regionType" jdbcType="INTEGER" typeHandler="com.product.mybatis.RegionTypeHandler"/>
        <parameter property="productType" jdbcType="INTEGER" typeHandler="com.product.mybatis.ProductTypeHandler"/>
        <parameter property="coverageStartDate" jdbcType="DATE"/>            
        <parameter property="zip" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
        <parameter property="county" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
    </parameterMap>
```

The QuoteVO has all the attributes populated. This works fine in ibatis. But i'm migrating to mybatis and when I run the application, I'm getting the below error. Application uses Oracle DB and Spring. Datatype for county in DB is VARCHAR2. Please advice.

```
2017-05-09 10:04:19 INFO  IFPProductServiceImpl:36 -  calling saveQuote QuoteVO [quoteId=null, applicationType=I, coverageStartDate=Tue May 09 10:04:18 PDT 2017, zip=90001, county=LA, subscriberNumber=12345]
2017-05-09 10:04:20 ERROR ExceptionControllerAdvice:17 - org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='county', mode=null, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #6 with JdbcType VARCHAR . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

Comment: Ad 1) parameterMap is deprecated, check the docs here: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html 
Ad2 ) This usually happens if one of your values is null and Mybatis doesn't know what type should be used. Because of this behaviour I always specify jdbcType for each parameter in the query like this:  INSERT INTO xx (id) VALUES (#{id, jdbcType=INTEGER}

Comment: Btw, your selectKey resultType is string and id in the parameterMap is INTEGER. Doesn't seem right.